# Css Selector for a class except the first element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="different_class"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I want to apply a border to all the children divs with (.child), except the first one. so in the end all the children divs except (.different_class) and (.child:eq(0)) (I don't want to use nth-child as in the real problem I might not have .different_class div) will have the border.

I think the solution might be to use :not() selector, but I'm not quite sure how. Thanks'

Comment: `:eq()` is not a CSS selector by the way. It's part of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I have been very confused with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/5XuE3/

```
#container div.child + div.child
{
border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.child { some css }
.child:first-child { other styling }
```

**EDIT**

Why does not work? Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb2fs/).

Comment: This doesn't work, "so in the end all the children divs except (.different_class) and (.child:eq(0))" thanks anyway

Comment: @Alvaro please see the update. Although I see now that you do not ask for the nth-child, it still works. Only tested with Chrome though.

Comment: There is no `.different_class` in your fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

`+` selector will work in this case because all elements that have `child` class are together but it would not work if another different element (or with another class) will be between them.

This happens because `+` selector will match all elements that are placed **immediately after** another `div.child`.

Example:

```css
#container div.child + div.child{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="different_class">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
    <div class="different_class">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
</div>
```

To avoid that, we can use `~` selector, that will match all elements that are **preceded** by `div.child`, **not necessary** that it will be **immediately  after** it. So it will not match the first `div` with `child` class but will match the rest of `divs` with `child` class without take in consideration the rest of elements.

Example:

```css
#container div.child ~ div.child{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="different_class">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
    <div class="child">Test</div>
</div>
```